# Dealing with Ferma ORM/OGM and remote connection

Tags: amazon-web-services, database-connection

I'm working with a graph database on AWS.

At the moment I can write and read vertices and edges using Gremlin-Driver as well as query the graph with Kotlin (or Java) and gremlin language, but I would like to use an ORM/OGM in order to map the contents of the database into models. The [Ferma](https://github.com/Syncleus/Ferma) project does exactly what I want, but all the examples in the documentation refer to databases in memory.

How can i set up the configuration (host, port, credentials, ...) for a remote connection?

Answer (score 0):

**I am the lead Ferma developer**

Ferma is simply a thin wrapper around TinkerPop. The way in which you connect to the database itself is through TinkerPop directly (using whichever driver for your DB they have). This will produce a TinkerPop Graph object, which you then pass to the constructor of a FramedGraph class provided by Ferma. That is all there is to it.